# I need to fix my windows boot loader with a 2 GB USB drive

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, bootloader, windows-installation

Here's an interesting problem for you guys.

I've installed Linux in a partition on the same hard drive with Windows 10, intending to dual boot.

But now I can't boot into Windows because the boot-loader only gives me the option to boot into Linux.

I've read that I would need to create a Windows 10 USB key and run bootsect.exe, but the problem is the Windows iso is 4.1 GB, but I only have a 2GB USB Flash Drive.

Since I won't need all the installation files, is there a way to load only the files that I will need to run bootsect on the flash drive in order to make do with just 2 GB?

Thanks!

Comment: Borrow one- problem solved ;)

Comment: Create a Win 10 Recovery USB - you will need less than 1 GB ;)